# Pop up window and Play audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, popupwindow

I am trying to pop up window and play audio when my website load.

My code is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
  function popup(windowname) { 
    window.open("", windowname, 'width=600,height=800'); 
  }
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body onLoad="popup('popup audio')">

</body>
</html>
```

I want to execute following audio tag inside the popup

`<audio controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="http://95.154.254.157:11648/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: I want to popup a window when my website will run and that popup window will play audio

Comment: As a user, I would ask you to reconsider. If this is targeted at a general audience, be aware that if you open a popup and play unrequested audio, I would simply close your site and never return.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins thanks for that but i need that code.

Comment: Your original code worked. It's just that the audio seems to be bad. If you try browsing to the src you provided, it gives a "Mime type not supported" error. Fix the audio, and you will have it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you can create a popup window on page load, but to my knowledge, you need to link the source as the target for the popup window. EX: Google.com

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="playAudio()">

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()">Try it</button>

<script>
function playAudio() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "width=200", "height=780");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```